# how to make a git repository clonable by anyone

Tags: git

I have a remote repository on the cloud on a debian 9 server running apache and git.  Apache is set to redirect to https/SSL

How do I make it so that anyone can clone my repository without needing a login on that server?

On my local computer, which has login credentials as user git on that server,

```
git clone git@example.com:~/MyProject
```

works
but on another computer, does not work

I tried

```
$ git clone ssh://example.com/~/MyProject.git

Cloning into 'MyProject'...
user@example.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: How do you config you git server?

Comment: How should I config my git server?

Do I even have a git server?  Probably not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup public git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620439/how-to-setup-public-git-repositories)

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Public-Access

Comment: http://comparegithosting.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you want an unauthenticated server, you can config [git daemon](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon) to use `git` protocol to serve the project.

```
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=/MyProject/ ~/MyProject/
```

Then user can clone the project by `git clone git://example.com/MyProject`
(Note that you should place an empty file called `git-daemon-export-ok` under `~/MyProject/.git` to tell the daemon it is ok to export this project to public.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your repo through ssh, you should probably access it with the `git` user

Try opening a regular ssh connexion : `ssh git@example.com`

If you use the correct password, or set a ssh key to have a passwordless connexion, you should be able to clone your repo :

```
git clone git@example.com:~/MyProject.git
# or
git clone ssh://git@example.com/~/MyProject.git
```